# PHP - skip else statement on boolean

Tags: php, boolean, getter-setter

I have command handler that returns `approve` param which is *boolean* type and can be **true** or **false**. I have specific setters there and I defined it like:

```
if ($command->approve()) {
        $schedule->setApproval(true);
        $schedule->setApprovalAt(new \DateTime());
    } else {
        $schedule->setApproval(false);
        $schedule->setApprovalAt(null);
}
```

Is there any cleaner approach to this? Can we skip this kind of repetition and using of `else` clause?

Comment: For `setApproval` you can use the output of the function. But for `setApprovalAt` you'll still need an 'if' with eg a ternary operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make this a two-liner with the help of PHP's ternary operator:

```php
$schedule->setApproval($command->approve());
$schedule->setApprovalAt($command->approve() ? new \DateTime() : null);
```

Comment: This way is ok but i think you had better assign to a value
$isApproved = $command->approve();
$schedule->setApproval($isApproved);
$schedule->setApprovalAt($isApproved? new \DateTime() : null);

Comment: Calling approve() twice may not work, as already stated save the value and test it.